# Update a value in nested object of array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i'm working with state but i'm stuck a little bit with the value of state

```
state= {
        ingredients: [
            {Cheese: 0},
            {Bacon: 0}
        ]
    }
<button onClick={this.add}>ADD</button>
```

i want to change the value of Cheese to 1 when i click the button 
i couldn't find the solution

Comment: what does your this.add function look like? is it bound properly?

Comment: add = () =>{
        this.setState({
            ingredients: this.state.ingredients[0].Cheese + 1
        })
        
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code.

Comment: @Aziz, that's incorrect, it will make state = `{ingredients: 1}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 add = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const ingredients = prevState.ingredients.map(ing => {
        if (ing["Cheese"]) {
          return { ...ing, Cheese: ing["Cheese"] + 1 };
        }
        return ing;
      });
      return {
        ingredients
      };
    });
  };
```